# get iframe title and echo in html

Tags: php, html, iframe

i load my iframe src from address bar like:
http://site.com/demo.php?go=http://google.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET["go"];?>">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to get iframe title and echo it in demo.php title tag… 
is it possible?

Comment: i think in your case better use `javascript` than using php to request the page from server-side to fetch the title and then call the same url again in the client-side window

Comment: According to this: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php you're using the correct syntax.

So is it possible? Yes is the answer. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht first of all your are posting deprecated function, second thing is your suggestion doesn't fit his requirement

Comment: $_GET isn't deprecated

Comment: none of your answers work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript instead. Like this:

`var iframeTitle = document.getElementById("myIframe").documentElement.title`

Comment: Note - this will only work if it's on the same domain as the parent page

Comment: I don't think he's after this.. He wants to retrieve the url as a GET parameter from the requested GET request

Comment: I don't think he wants to be a GET parameter.

Comment: so how can i call it in <title > tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse and retrieve the `go` URI with these kind of functions

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

and then source the `iframe` calling `getURLParameter('go')`
Btw, as you wish, to put it in a title tag, you have to add this `$('title').val(getURLParameter('go'))` (using `jQuery`) or in pure javascript `document.element.getElementsByTagName('title').value = getURLParameter('go')`

You should read some javascript doc !

Comment: how can i echo or print it in title tag?

Comment: see my edit, and don't forget to upvote if you're satisfied by the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to control and sanitize your variable 'go'.